# Are phenols good antioxidants?

Tags: organic-chemistry

Are phenols good antioxidants? If so what makes them good? I think it is because they oxidize easily but I'm not sure how that helps.

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/85486/how-do-antioxidants-work https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/62729/what-makes-a-good-antioxidant

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/16088/what-has-stronger-antioxidant-potential-bht-or-bha

Answer (score 4):

Phenolic compounds, or in general aromatics actually, has electrons which many oxidants can easily abstract or bind to molecule.

http://www.springer.com/cda/content/document/cda_downloaddocument/9781441978257-c1.pdf?SGWID=0-0-45-1106848-p174056970

From the above link in page 17,
[image]

as you see the highest rates, order of magnitude or even more higher ones come from aromatics, or at least pi-bond between carbons. It can reasonably assumed that if you have these compounds in a mixture, the possibility of any oxidant introduced reacts with them is higher than the other ones. In short, they are good anti-oxidants in that way.